# When I add google analytics to my website the second part dont show up in my source

Tags: function, google-analytics

I add the whole Google analytics code but the part of the function does not show up..

You can check out my source at http://vivamaroc.nl/

I did alot of research before I started this post so I hope anyone could help me out with this problem.

:-) Thanks alot.

Comment: I got a update i removed the lines:

Answer (score 0):

Try pasting this code instead of yours exactly before the closing `</body>` tag.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var _gaq = _gaq || [];
_gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-3252844-6']);
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

(function() {
  var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
  ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
  var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
})();
</script>
```

Comment: I removed (function() { and 
})();
 lines and now it is working, is it fine so? Or wont google analytics show me the real statistics? When I go to google analytics it seems like it works well :)?